# How to create custom editor/display templates in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, templates, editortemplates

I would like to make custom editor templates for different data types in ASP.NET MVC (to use with `Html.EditorFor()`), including rewriting the existing templates. The ultimate goal is to create a mini-framework where each editor supports javascript notifications about being changed, and I can show a message to the user that there are unsaved changes in the page. (Maybe there's something existing already?)

I can find many questions pertaining to problems with such templates, but nowhere can I find a tutorial or manual on creating them. Where do they go? Is there any special syntax? How does a template get selected? What information is available in the template and how do I access it? Etc.

So - where can I find out all about these templates?

Comment: The best guide to templates that I know of is Brad Wilson's guide: [Brad Wilson: ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates, Part 1: Introduction](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) While this is for MVC2, this behaviour hasn't changed for MVC3.

Comment: Also take a look at http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/04/26/mvc-2-templates/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425994/mvc-4-custom-template-for-bool-razor
Just take care that bool -->  Boolean.cshtml

Answer (score 3):

Check and download ASP.NET MVC 3 Futures on http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781 and see how the default source code looks. Note: this works for MVC 4 as well.

Comment: Nice! Also, here's the [source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) for MVC4, found from your link. This will be useful! :)

Comment: Especially given that a lot of code moves from Codeplex to GitHub, it would be much better if your answer actually contained an answer instead of just a link