# How to serialize model into hidden fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization, hidden-field

I have complex  model like this:

```
public class MyModel 
{
    public SubModel SubModel1 {get;set;}
    public SubModel SubModel2 {get;set;}
    public SubModel SubModel3 {get;set;}
}

public class SubModel
{
    public int Field1 {get;set;}
    public string Field2 {get;set;}
}
```

Depends on some cases on the view I need to implement the next logic:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.SubModel1);
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SubModel2);
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SubModel3);
```

My problem is that Html.HiddenFor() works only for single value, not for model. So is there way to serialize model(or part) into hidden fields?

Comment: Could you put each in it's own div, like `<div class="sub1">@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.SubModel1)</div>`, and then show/hide the one you need with javascript?

Comment: I would XML serialize the entire Model with it's submodels, then encrypt the serialized string before storing it in the hidden field. You do the reverse to get the original model back.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem, its just an idea I had and my rep won't allow me to comment.

How about creating a custom editor template for each of your Sub Models: [How to create custom editor/display templates in ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497183/how-to-create-custom-editor-display-templates-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

You can then create individual hidden for controls inside your custom template for each property from your sub model.

Answer (score 0):

Hum... if you want to go through that way, you can consider to serialize this model to javascript instead of trying to serialize to a input hidden. [Take a look at this](http://info.titodotnet.com/2012/03/aspnet-mvc-3-converting-serializing-net.html). this is a good example of model serialization to script.

Another approach: if this model contains data that user will eventually see, perhaps you should consider to store it in a view and then keep the view hidden until the time to show up. In this particular case, it is even better if you could use ajax to request the model to the server only when requested by the user.

Another approach: you could avoid loading this SubModel during the page opening and load inside the action after it is triggered.

---

I am not saying that you need, but just for the record, you can explore another forms of maintaining data in the server for short periods of time: [TempData, ViewData and ViewBag](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem).

Hope that one of these approaches could be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be able to create your own custom templates for HiddenFor like you can for EditorFor, so I would just create your own partial template and then use that.

Create a file in Views/Shared/HiddenSubModel.cshtml

```
@model SubModel

@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Field1)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Field2)
```

Then use this in the calling page with

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.SubModel1);
@Html.Partial("HiddenSubModel", Model.SubModel2)
@Html.Partial("HiddenSubModel", Model.SubModel3)
```